# Частная производная в точке. Python 3

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

Как при помощи средств Python или библиотеки math вычислить частные производные для х и у двумерной функции. Решение должно быть общим.

Answer (score 2):

Если функция известна, то находите аналитическое решение и по нему вычисляете частные производные в нужной точке

```
F(x,y) = sin(x) + exp(-2xy)
dF/dx  = cos(x) - 2y*exp(-2xy)
dF/dy  = 2x*exp(-2xy)

dF/dx (x0, y0) = cos(x0) - 2y0*exp(-2x0y0)
dF/dy (x0, y0) = 2x0*exp(-2x0y0)
```

Если неизвестна или продифференцировать проблематично, то вычисляете значения функции в точках, отстоящих на малое расстояние по каждой из осей, прямо по определению производной

```
dF/dx (x0, y0) = (F(x0 + deltax, y0) - F(x0, y0)) / deltax
dF/dy (x0, y0) = (F(x0, y0 + deltay) - F(x0, y0)) / deltay
```

Comment: Я в принципе понимаю как действовать при известной функции, но мне необходимо реализовать градиентный спуск для функции с двумя параметрами, наибольшая проблема в том что я еще не знаком с самим определением производной)) Тем более частной)) Поэтому хотелось бы узнать возможно какой-то общий случай нахождения градиента и ,если вас не затруднит, с комментариями про каждый член формулы.

Comment: Градиент - это вектор из двух (для 2d) указанных частных производных. Курс или книжку по матану я заменить не могу. Мне кажется, уже некуда более конкретно показать, чем то, что я написал.